# Using select information from array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array of the form [a b, a b, a b,...] and I want to create a new array of just the b values. I have tried a .split(" ") but it keeps coming up with an index outside the bounds of the array error.

```
for (int sequence = 0; sequence < FileIndex.Length; sequence++)
                    {
                        string[] SplitIndex = FileIndex[sequence].Split(' ');
                        sequence++;
                        WriteLine(SplitIndex[sequence]);
                     }
```

Comment: `sequence++` inside The for loop is not needed. That will increase the value of `sequence` twice on each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int sequence = 0; sequence < FileIndex.Length; sequence++)
{
    string[] SplitIndex = FileIndex[sequence].Split(' ');
    sequence++;
    WriteLine(SplitIndex[1]);
}
```

Once you split, in the `SplitIndex` you will have 2 elements: **"a"** and **"b"**. If you want to access **"b"** you will have to use `SplitIndex[1]`. You are currently using `SplitIndex[sequence]`

Also, you have `sequence++` twice. One in the `for` statement, and one inside the loop. You should remove it from the loop.

Comment: This will not work because of the extra `sequence++` inside `for`.

Comment: This works fine but it produces 8 leading spaces which I can't get rid of so that I can run a comparison against another variable

Comment: @tymtam I have already edited for the sequence++ dublication before you added your comment.
CallumMcNeilage I dont know why you have this problem. Perhaps you should tell me what FileIndex[sequence] shows and if it has more than 1 space.
You can always use TrimStart() to remove the spaces

Answer (score 0):

You could also use LINQ here:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var stringArray = new string[] { "a b", "a b", "a b" };

var result = stringArray
    .Select(str => str.Split(' ').Last())
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", result) + " }");
// { b, b, b }
```

Explanation:

- Select every element in the array with [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)
- Split each string with [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) and take the last element with [`Enumerable.Last()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=netframework-4.8). You could also just index the second element with `[1]` here as well.
- Convert the result to an array with [`List.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netframework-4.8). Optionally you could just leave the result as an `IEnumerable<string>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

## `for` way

1. Remove `sequence++;`
2. Change `WriteLine(SplitIndex[sqequence]);` to `WriteLine(SplitIndex[1]);`

```
for (int sequence = 0; sequence < FileIndex.Length; sequence++)
{
  string[] SplitIndex = FileIndex[sequence].Split(' ');
  //sequence++;
  WriteLine(SplitIndex[1]);
}
```

## Linq way

```
//Note: no error handling
var bees = FileIndex.Select(fi => fi.Split(' ')[1]);
```

---

You can add error handling

```
var bees = test.Select(fi => fi.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault() ?? "'No b!'" );
```

### Test

```
var test = new string[] { "a a", "a b", "a c", "a ", "" };

var bees = test.Select(fi => fi.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault() ?? "'No b!'" );

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", bees));
```

```
a b c 'No b!' 'No b!'
```